# Cannot disconnect HDD due to being the "System" volume

Tags: windows-10, partitioning

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Suieg.png]

I want to remove "Temp Storage" from my PC since I do not need it anymore. When formatting, I was told I cannot format due to the volume being the "System Volume." Searching the net only gives "system reserved" and other irrelevant results. Is there a way to move this partition to (C:) or at least delete it?

I am using windows 10, freshly wiped from windows 7 (Neither drives were used for windows 7)

**EDIT** I am also currently looking for other results as of this edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to move this partition to (C:) or at least delete it?

The files used to initially boot a computer are different than your operating system files. In this case, "System" refers to where the files used to initially boot the computer itself (not the OS) are stored.

This entry is required on all PCs (and so it cannot be deleted entirely) but it can be moved.

**Important**

The following steps should work for a traditional MBR drive setup.

If you use UEFI/GPT, however, you may  need to use a different approach. While the program I recommend is UEFI/GPT compatible ([you can read more about it here](https://neosmart.net/wiki/easybcd/uefi/)), *I have cannot verify all the steps will be the same for non-MBR setups*.

[This How-to Geek article](https://www.howtogeek.com/245610/how-to-check-if-a-disk-uses-gpt-or-mbr-and-how-to-convert-between-the-two/) has some good general information as well.

If you are unsure about your setup, select the drive in the Windows Disk Management Tool and select Properties.

[image: Windows Disk Management Tool Properties]

Under the Volumes tab, there should be an entry for "Partition style" -- either "Master Boot Record (MBR)" or "GUID Partition Table (GPT)".

[image: Windows Disk Management Tool Partition Style]

If it says "GUID Partition Table", you may wish to proceed with caution.

*One final note -- though this does not apply in your case, it is also worth mentioning that the files used to boot a PC can only reside on "Primary" (not "Logical") partitions*.

---

**Changing The System Partition**

There are multiple tools available to help you manage such things but you will likely want to take a look at [EasyBCD](https://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/).

First, download the program. Don't worry about the "Buy Now" stuff, there is a free version. Scroll to the bottom of the page and select the non-commercial version by clicking the "Register" button. You will be taken to a page requesting a name and email address but you can (currently) simply ignore this and click "Download".

Once installed, you can follow [their instructions](https://neosmart.net/wiki/easybcd/basics/changing-the-boot-partition/) on how to resolve this issue:

1. Access the EasyBCD  “BCD Backup/Repair” page and select the "Change boot drive" option.
2. Assuming you do not wish to change the location of any items in the "File" fields, press "Perform Action".
3. You will be prompted to "Select A New Boot Partition". Select the drive you’d like to use as the new boot partition (e.g C:):

[image: EasyBCD BCD Backup/Repair Page]

The instructions go on to explain:

> When you confirm the selection, EasyBCD will automatically:
>
> - Install the BOOTMGR bootloader to the selected partition
> - Make the selected partition active
> - Install the bootloader to both the bootsector and the MBR of the selected partition
> - Copy all entries from the old boot partition to the newly-selected one
> - Update partition references to work with the new boot partition

Furthermore:

> EasyBCD will not delete or remove boot files from the current boot partition. As a result, you may revert to it without difficulty or dataloss but you will also need to remove them yourself at a later time.

**Caveats**

> If the partition which is to take over control of the boot is on a different HDD from the current boot partition, you will also need to change your BIOS to put the new drive before the old one in the boot sequence, otherwise the old (untouched) boot files will continue to be in control.

You can do this in the BIOS alone, but I would suggest perhaps temporarily disconnecting the "Temp Drive" just to make sure the configuration was correct.

The other option is to simply switch the connections for each drive in the PC
(connect the "Temp Drive" to the "Windows 10" connection and vice versa).

Either way, the "Windows 10" drive should be listed as "Disk 1" and have the "System" entry in the Windows Disk Management Tool.

And as a final note:

> This obviously does not apply if the two partitions share a HDD. The switch of the “active” status will do everything needed in that case.

This is not applicable in your specific case but may be if you ever decide to change the boot partition again.

Comment: Hello. I was searching for solutions and found that EasyBCD is actually a legit program (I ignored it early in search results). I used it and fixed the boot issue immediately. I'll mark you as the answer, thanks.

Comment: Yeah it's hard to tell sometimes... Genuinely glad you got it working though. And thanks for the checkmark. =)